# Does this edit change the meaning of the question?

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-question, title

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77919622) originally had the title:

> Keyboard shortcut suggestions in VScode

User [@starball](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11107541/starball) posted an answer, then changed the title to:

> I want to learn VS Code keyboard shortcuts. How can I get a counter of how many times I use a mouse for something that I could do via keyboard?

I don't think that reflect the question at all. How did a "is there a feature that suggests keyboard shortcut when I use the mouse for an action" question become "I want a mouse click counter"?

Comment: That *doesn't* appear to be what the OP is asking, in my view; they referenced a feature that does that in a different tool but that's not the end result they want.

Comment: I'm guessing `keyboard shortcut missed (1) time` sounds similiar to a counter,  so that would be understandable. However, `I want to learn VS Code keyboard shortcuts` is just putting words in OP's mouth, don't do that.

Comment: Isn't "keyboard shortcut missed (1) time" - i.e. what the body of the question asks for - a counter of how many times one uses a mouse for something that one could do via keyboard?

Comment: @Cuzy The original question read "I was wondering if there is the same feature in VScode so i can get used to using shortcuts without actually going over the list of them?" - so I don't think "I want to learn VS Code keyboard shortcuts" is an unreasonable interpretation of OP's intent.

Comment: Seeing how wildly opinions about what the questions asks for diverge: Why do we discuss what it does say instead of closing the question because it's not clear what it says?

Comment: Why not just leave it alone and let it be answered? I don't see a problem that needs to be solved here. If the op has a different intent they can express that as feedback themselves.

Comment: It's absolutely rediculous that that question got closed. Ffs, can Meta pedantics be left out of perfectly answerable SO questions for a change?! ___One___ dude misinterpreted the question and blindly focused on the _least_ important aspect of the question, a counter, which OP didn't even mention other than when describing the popup contents. It's very clear that OP just wants some __feedback__ when he performs an __action__ that has a __keybind__. The counter isn't important in there.

Comment: Is it just me or is starball's profile page thoroughly broken?

Comment: @DBS looks [just fine](https://web.archive.org/web/20240202085234/https://stackoverflow.com/users/11107541/starball?tab=profile) to me. what are you talking about?

Comment: @DBS It is broken due to starball having misnested tags in their *About me* section (namely, one `<div>`, one `<code>`, one `<table>` and other table tags).

Comment: @DBS & InSync It is broken due to bad programming (injection) by SO Inc. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396347/eeek-footer-can-be-broken-when-certain-code-is-inserted-to-a-post/396353#396353

Comment: @philipxy I assumed as much, but good to know it's a reported issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yea, Starball's edit did (IMO) indeed change the scope of the question.

OP asked for functionality similar to PyCharm's "Keyboard Promoter" popups, paraphrasing the contents of the popups:

> it pops up a little window on the bottom with something like "keyboard shortcut missed (1) time" . I was wondering if there is the same feature in VScode so i can get used to using shortcuts without actually going over the list of them?

Now, if you'd look at what those popups actually contain, the *counter* is the **least** important aspect of'm:
[image]

There's keyboard shortcuts in there ***and*** a mention of what action he missed.

With the edited title, an answer that ***only*** shows a "missed shortcuts" counter would've answered the question.

I've removed the "counting" aspect from that title, as that's not something the OP specifically mentioned. The *"Hey you missed a shortcut for <function>"* popup was more central to the question.

Now, the question remains as it was, with a more descriptive title, whilst not invalidating Starball's answer.

Comment: When the title [was changed](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77919622/3) (12:01:06Z), [there was no extension](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77920016/1) mentioned in Starball's answer (11:59:42Z). They only added it *[after](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77920016/2)* changing the title (12:06:52Z).

Comment: @InSync That's all within 10 minutes of each other. Starball might as well have found the extension before editing the title.

Comment: Doesn't the OP's reference example of "... missed (1) time" show counting?

Comment: Well, sure, but OP seemed to have much more focus on actually getting the feedback at all. He didn't specifically mention count, other than in that example output.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: Right, but emphasizing that part in the question title turns it into an X-Y problem.  The useful part is being shown what the keyboard shortcut *is*, not just that there is one or how many times you clicked.  (It was already an X-Y problem in terms of quoting that part of the PyCharm popup instead of the useful part, but doubling down on that is unhelpful.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm not question that something else is useful. I'm questioning the assertion that the OP did not ask for/mention a counter.

Answer (score 11):

The edit was an improvement overall, but it did change the meaning a bit. A further refinement to focus the title on 'prompting the user for missed shortcuts' or similar would be better than just asking for 'a counter incrementing the number of times a potential shortcut went unused', in my opinion.

Comment: see rev one of the question. there is _no_ request to know what shortcut was missed. only a request for a count of how many times one "missed" using a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @starball The title of the question was "Keyboard shortcut **suggestions** in VScode" (emphasis mine). The question body also stated "[...] so I can get used to using shortcuts [...]". That seems to me like OP is clearly interested in _learning to use the shortcuts_, not _just_ being told how many they missed.

Comment: and I agree that that's what they should be learning. that's what I tried to show them how to do in my answer post

Answer (score 3):

> I don't think that reflect the question at all. How did a "is there a feature that suggests keyboard shortcut when I use the mouse for an action" question become "I want a mouse click counter"?

Full disclosure: I edited the question first, attempting to remove noise.

As I read it, the question very clearly did describe baseline functionality in PyCharm which involved counting something. This text was in the original:

> it pops up a little window on the bottom with something like "keyboard shortcut missed (1) time"

The clear implication is that the number in parentheses would increase if the user continued to "miss" keyboard shortcuts. It also said:

> where lets say you use your cursor for something that has a keyboard shortcut

Putting those two ideas together (which I tried to preserve in my edit) sure sounds to me *exactly* like "a counter of how many times I use a mouse for something that I could do via keyboard".

So, no, the question wasn't asking for "a feature that suggests keyboard shortcut[s]" - it never said anything about suggesting a specific shortcut (i.e., saying what keys to press to get the same effect). The title edit accurately describes the requested feature.

It just happens that, according to starball, *(nearly) every action performed with a mouse* could have been done with a keyboard shortcut instead, thus the counter would count (nearly) all clicks. I don't use either IDE (or any IDE, really), so I can't evaluate this claim. But I can't see any malfeasance here.

That said, it seems likely that the specific counting behaviour is not *essential* to the desired functionality. Arguably there isn't an exact specification for the desired feature - but arguably, it wouldn't be useful. The apparent goal isn't to make a counter go up; the apparent goal is to *get reminders about keyboard shortcuts* in order to *improve retention / usage rate* for those keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Starball's title, _"I want to learn VS Code keyboard shortcuts. How can I get a counter of how many times I use a mouse for something that I could do via keyboard?"_, can be answered with a plugin that ___only___ shows a counter. I think that's the main issue with that title.

Comment: I'm not sure why such a plugin doesn't satisfy the OP, though.

Comment: OP specifically asked for a popup to happen when he misses a shortcut. A counter that only counts missed shortcuts is not that.

Comment: The original title was "*Keyboard shortcut suggestions*". It wasn't repeated in the body, but it too was a part of the question. To me, what OP wants are keyboard suggestions, which means they would be satisfied even if the hypothetical popup would just say, for instance, "There's a shortcut for what you just did: Key1 + Key2".

Comment: @Cerbrus the example given in rev one of the question does not include a keyboard shortcut suggestion- just a counter. do I find that astounding and perplexing? yes. did I change the meaning of the question to change it into what I expected to be asked? no. because I generally try to avoid doing that.

Comment: @starball It does _explicitly_ mention popups appearing when shortcuts are missed. What I find perplexing is that anyone could think that the ___sole___ point of that question is ___only___ a _counter_. There were so many indications in there to so much more than that... Frankly, this looks like wilful ignorance to me.

Comment: @Cerbrus how many of those interactions involve the _original_ asker of the question? my count is zero.

Comment: What interactions? I'm talking about the original version of the post. There's ___no way___ that ___only___ a counter somewhere that increments when you miss a shortcut, satisfied the OP. The OP mentions getting used to shortcuts __multiple__ times. How does ___only___ showing a counter help?! See the 2nd line of my answer, the whole problem with your title was that something that shows a big incrementing counter on screen _and nothing more_ would've answered that. That wasn't what OP was asking for.

Comment: @Cerbrus by the way, in case it's not clear, I don't believe that having only a counter is helpful. but I wasn't trying to act maliciously. I simply read the question, made a good faith effort to interpret it faithfully as it was written by the original asker, and then wrote an answer to the question as I understood it to be.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the original content of the question post:

> #### Keyboard shortcut suggestions in VScode
>
> I used to code on Pycharm and the IDE has this feature where lets say you use your cursor for something that has a keyboard shortcut, it pops up a little window on the bottom with something like "keyboard shortcut missed (1) time" .
> I was wondering if there is the same feature in VScode so i can get used to using shortcuts without actually going over the list of them?

Here is the motive:

> so i can get used to using shortcuts without actually going over the list of them?

Here is the example of what they want to see:

> keyboard shortcut missed (1) time

The example does not include a keyboard shortcut. It just has a counter.

At the time of this writing, the asker has not made any other revisions to the post. All the editors are other users.

The original title is vague and not descriptive of the motive and what is being asked for. All that is given about what is being asked for is that example. I took it upon myself (and this is [a common practice of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4370/illuminator?userid=11107541)) to write a better title since I cared enough about the question to post an answer.

At the time of making my edit, I believed that my edit was reflective of the asker's question, given the information that was provided *in* the question post.

Cerbrus has since helpfully edited the question on behalf of the asker of the question to show that the desired feature actually includes showing *what* the keybinding is that is being "missed".

Could I have figured out myself that the mentioned extension's functionality included showing the keybinding that was "missed"? Yeah. Easily. If I'd just looked up the plugin's marketplace page, I'd have seen the demo gif. And for that I am sorely embarrassed. But could the asker of the question have included that information in their question post and in their example so I wouldn't have to go off-site to understand what's (probably- I'm still not 100% sure since the asker hasn't come back to spell things out) being asked? Also yes, and also easily. But in the interest of letting all the emotions die down, I'll take the blame. I've updated my answer post. Let's leave it at that, shall we?

Comment: _"The example does not include a keyboard shortcut"_ because OP was paraphrasing. Have a look at [what OP was talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPfUe.png) There's keyboard shortcuts in there ___and___ a mention of what action he missed.

Comment: @Cerbrus see edit (last paragraph)

Comment: If there's a lesson to learn here for the future, I think it's to avoid amplifying X-Y problem aspects of a question (by putting them in the title).  But on the other hand, finding what makes a question specific and unique is also an important thing for editing.  Totally understandable that the querent's very odd choice of which part of the PyCharm message to quote created confusion. Without taking unreasonable amounts of time trying to think through what an unclear question is probably asking for or should be asking for, mistakes will happen, but are fixable by the OP or others like this case

Comment: At least with the benefit of hindsight, I think *so i can get used to using shortcuts without actually going over the list of them?* is the key clue that they (also) want to be shown what the shortcut is, so they don't have to go digging in the list of shortcuts to find out what they could have pressed.